# Force the abstract onto a new page

Tags: page-breaking, abstract

I have a document that has the header "Abstract" at the very bottom of the first page, and then the actual text of the abstract is on the second page. The rest of the first page is taken up with author information.

I would like to force my abstract to start on a new page.

I have tried to do this using \vspace and \pagebreak and \newpage etc., but not of them seem to change anything. Is this because my class file overrides everything?

I am using the class file aastex.

Comment: `\clearpage` just before abstract?

Comment: I tried that too. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a complete example code that reproduces the problem. Without that it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 2):

It's guesswork without a complete example, but let's see how my psychic powers are working today. Try adding this to your preamble.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\abstractname}{\newpage}{}{}
```